# Find the equilibrium point and its variance in stochastic data?

Tags: covariance, autocorrelation

I have some data of the form [image: stochastic process]

I need to find the point where it starts reaching equilibrium (as I can see from the graph around 1000 iteration) and how much fluctuating the data points are. Is there a function to do that? I have been playing around with autocorrelation but nothing works.

Any guidance/readings suggestion is truly appreciated.

DISCLAIMER: I have zero to minimum background in statistics but I have been asked to present my data that way...

Comment: Would it be of any use to process the data in reverse order to find the point at which it *stops* appearing to be in equilibrium?